# SubSonic 3.0 Migrations Vs. SimpleRepository Auto-Migrations: Foreign keys support?

Tags: sqlite, subsonic, foreign-keys

I'm considering using SubSonic to create and access an SQLite database.
Not sure yet what flavor fits better for me though I tend to prefer the SimpleRepository approach.
Indeed I don't expect my DB to do much more than storing my objects and basic querying.

I've been through to docs but there are still a few points unclear to me or that I'd like to have confirmation for:

1/ Does "3.0 Migrations" fully support SQLite ?

2/ Using SimpleRepository, is the auto-migration feature equivalent to the 'regular' migration feature or does it support only a subset of it (apart from the incremental aspect) ?

3/ In particular, how can one specify a foreign key like it can be done with Migration.CreateForeignKey(TableColumn oneTable, TableColumn manyTable)?
I would love a [SubSonicForeignKey(Table, Column)] attribute to flag a property as such for helping relationship navigations and also indexing the column.

I suppose I'm dreaming, and the best solution I've found so far is like described in this post:
http://www.frozenmountain.com/blog/post/Automatic-Foreign-Objects-in-SubSonic3-SimpleRepository.aspx

4/ But this still can't address the missing index. So to the Subsonic Team: Any chance to see a [SubSonicIndex] attribute some day?

Thanks!